# cx_freeze can not import numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyqt, cx-freeze

my main py file is working correctly, but when i froze this with cx_freeze and i try to open, it occurs an error and can not open.
it says:
[image]

and this is my setup.py :

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options = {"packages":["lxml","gzip","requests"]}

setup(  name = "name",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "description",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("file.py", icon=os.path.join("icon_64x64.ico"), base="Win32GUI")])
```

..

Comment: What version of cx_Freeze are you using? Have you tried forcing the inclusion of numpy in the list of packages along with lxml, gzip and requests? Have you looked at the offending line in pandas and find out what it is complaining about? Sometimes it is expecting something in the file system.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, even if I use **options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["numpy.lib.format"]}},** in the setup file, it still won't work. This is SO frustrating, I simply can't compile numpy in cx_freeze, or pyinstaller or py2exe... it just won't work, in any python version (2.7 or 3.6).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me python 3.6:

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "numpy"], "includes": ["numpy"]}
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="Hello World",
      version="0.1",
      description="My GUI application!",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable("main.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: This worked for me, too. The key addition was: `setup(options='build_exe': {'packages': ['numpy'], 'includes': ['numpy'])`, which forced cx_freeze to copy my numpy install over to the build files.

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

find "_methods" in site-packages/numpy/core/ (Specific location in my case: C:\ProgramFile\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core) and copy it to build/exe.win32-2.7/lib/numpy/core/

Run now, it will works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Python 3.6.1 and cx_Freeze 5.1.1. My code was only importing pandas, which in turn tried to import numpy which failed due to missing dependancies. However, since my code was not directly trying to import numpy, I was not notified of this discrepancy by cx_Freeze.

I forced `import numpy` in my code, and cx_Freeze then appropriately notified me of the missing dependancies. After troubleshooting these, I removed `import numpy` from my code and the produced exe worked fine.

Maybe adding `import numpy` at the very beginning of your main could allow you to see what is missing?